# É correto utilizar List com ViewModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel

Possuo a `ViewModel` abaixo:

```
 public class Crm_AnaliseViewModel
{
    public string TAG { get; set; }
    public int ATUALIZACAO { get; set; }
    public string RELATORIOS { get; set; }
}
```

Então no `Controler` fiz:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Index(Crm_AnaliseViewModel model)
    {
        if (Session["cod_cli"] != null)
        {
            if(model == null)
            {
                model = new Crm_AnaliseViewModel();
            }

            int cod_cli = Convert.ToInt32(Session["cod_cli"]);

            List<Crm_AnaliseViewModel> TAG_List = new List<Crm_AnaliseViewModel>();

            var query = (from s in db.Crm_Analise
                         where s.cliente_CRM.Equals(cod_cli)
                         group s by s.TAG into g
                         select new
                         {
                            TG = g.Key,
                            AT = g.Max(t => t.data_creat),
                            RL = g.Count()
                        });

            foreach(var item in query)
            {
                model.TAG = item.TG;
                model.RELATORIOS = item.AT;
                model.ATUALIZACAO = item.RL;
                TAG_List.Add(model);
            }

            return View(TAG_List);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
    }
```

Seria correto, utilizar `List` para popular (se assim posso chamar) um `ViewModel`?

Comment: O seu código não precisa fazer um `foreach` se pode resumir isso de outra forma! não tem problemas em preencher um `foreach` o problema que eu estou vendo é no seu código agora!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não vejo problemas em fazer um `foreach` para preencher uma `ViewModel`, o problema do seu código é que não precisa fazer esse `foreach`, é desnecessário, ficando assim um ***exemplo***:

```
public class Crm_AnaliseViewModel
{
    public string TAG { get; set; }
    public int ATUALIZACAO { get; set; }
    public DateTime RELATORIOS { get; set; }
}

public async Task<ActionResult> Index(Crm_AnaliseViewModel model)
{
    if (Session["cod_cli"] != null)
    {
        int cod_cli = Convert.ToInt32(Session["cod_cli"]);

        var query = (from s in db.Crm_Analise
                        where s.cliente_CRM.Equals(cod_cli)
                        group s by s.TAG into g
                    select new Crm_AnaliseViewModel
                    {
                        TAG = g.Key,
                        RELATORIOS = g.Max(t => t.data_creat),
                        ATUALIZACAO = g.Count()
                    })
                    .ToList();

        return View(query);
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
    }
}
```

***Observação:*** retirei algumas variáveis porque o código não precisa, pelo menos o que está na pergunta.